# Moving a linux server to new hardware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware

We currently have a working coldfusion 9 server running on ubuntu. Its hardware is a lenovo thinkserver running raid 1. We want to move this server to a different lenovo server (slightly different hardware) and still raid 1. 
We can deal with a little bit of downtime, but clonezilla was giving me an estimate of >14 hours to do the job.

Does anyone have other advice for moving the server to the new hardware in a timely manner?

p.s. the hard drives cannot move with it, they are warrantied with each machine.

Comment: How much storage do you actually need to transfer?  Without a size, an estimate of 14 hours may be completely reasonable, or it may be insanely long.

Comment: realistically about 40gb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would install Ubuntu on the new hardware and then get any possible hardware issues worked out. After that, install any other software that you need and then rsync your data over to the new server.

If you have made a lot of customizations to the original server, you can still do this, just boot the new server with a live CD and then do the rsync'ing from there.  If you go that route, you'll need to make sure you have Grub installed correctly.

The advantage to using rsync for this process is that you can repeat it if anything changes on the source server, and not have to start all over.  (rsync will do a complete copy the first time, and just copy the differences the next time.)

Comment: Make sure you use -aH when doing rsync for copying the whole system or I would go eith axH and rsync every mountpoint